# append uiimages to a uiimage array

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, append, uiimage

I want my swift code below to append all of the images that are displayed in each tableview cell to be appended to an array. In this case the array is emptyA. I tried to do this action in aDDBTn. I am getting a compile error on

> let arrayValues2 = collect.compactMap { UIImage($0.self.image) }

with compactMap. I just want to appended thoses images to the array when the func is called.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var emptyA = [UIImage]()
    var addBTN = UIButton()
    var tableView = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setTableVIew()
        aDDBTn()
        
        
    }
    
    
    func setTableVIew(){
        
        
        addBTN.backgroundColor = .orange
        view.addSubview(addBTN)
        addBTN.addTarget(self, action: #selector(aDDBTn), for: .touchDown)
        
        
        let VCframe = view.frame
        let height = VCframe.height * 0.8
        let height2 = VCframe.height * 0.2
        let widthx = VCframe.width
        addBTN.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: height, width: widthx, height: height2)
        
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: widthx - 20, height: height)
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        
        tableView.register(customtv.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    
    
    var arr = [1,2,3,4]
    
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 118 }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customtv
      
    
        return cell
    }

    @objc func aDDBTn(){

        
        let collect = (0..<arr.count).compactMap { (tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)) as? customtv)?.lbl }
        let arrayValues2 = collect.compactMap { UIImage($0.self.image) }
        emptyA.append(contentsOf: arrayValues2)
        print("Empty Array" , emptyA)
    }
    
    
}
class customtv: UITableViewCell {
    lazy var backView : UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: self.frame.width  , height: 110))
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        print(self.frame.width)
        return view
    }()
    
    
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        backView.clipsToBounds = true
        backView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 6, width: bounds.maxX  , height: 110)
        
        
    }
    lazy var lbl : UIImageView = {
        let press = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 3, width: 120 , height: 50))
        press.backgroundColor = .yellow
        press.image = UIImage(named: "a2")
        
        return press
    }()
    
    
    

    
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(animated, animated: true)
        addSubview(backView)
 
        backView.addSubview(lbl)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `collect` is `[UIImageView]` based on the following line since `lbl` is of type `UIImageView`

```
let collect = (0..<arr.count).compactMap { (tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)) as? customtv)?.lbl }
```

As a result, you can access the image directly through the `image` property. Just change the following line

```
let arrayValues2 = collect.compactMap { UIImage($0.self.image) }
```

to

```
let arrayValues2 = collect.compactMap { $0.image }
```